# How to send post request to PayPal with buyer id

Tags: java, php, html, forms, paypal

I'm sending post data to PayPal (for example :item_number, item_name etc. )and want to add also buyer id . How can I do that ?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Daniel it is secure application so due to our company policy it is impossible to share real codes . Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Pay pal variable list include a 'custom' one. 
Just add a

```
`<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="the dynamic id value you want" />`
```

to the form of your paypal button and use it just as you use all of the other variables